# pass value to JQuery select2 with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am new to web development and learning how to have Select2 interact with data backend in Django following https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

In `http://localhost:8000/get_lvl0`, I have successfully loaded data.

```
[{"name": "OK"}, {"name": "WA"}, {"name": "VA"}, {"name": "DE"}, {"name": "RI"}, {"name": "IN"}, {"name": "PA"}, {"name": "IL"}, {"name": "TN"}, {"name": "MD"}]
```

But the values do not get loaded in page.

```
<select class="testing" multiple="multiple" name="lv0_es" style="width:30%">
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.testing').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an Lv0'
    });
}); 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#lv0_es').select2({
        ajax: {
        url: '/get_lvl0',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: function (params) {
            var queryParameters = {
            q: params.name
        }
            return queryParameters; 
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        }
}
});
});
<script>
```

There's no error in the console.

I also tried below to have ajax load data first then get a select2 but get error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` which I am not sure why it is triggered.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        ajax: {
        url: '/get_lvl0',
        dataType: 'json', //this line triggers error but I do not see why
        type: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
    if (data.errno == 200) {
        var str = "";
        data.datas.forEach(function (obj, index, array) {
            str += "<option value ='" + obj.name + "'>" + obj.name + "</option>"
        })}}
        $(".testing").html(str)
        $(".testing").select2();
}});
```

What needs to be changed here? Would be appreciated for front-end debugging tips as well. Thanks.

Comment: first load data in the DOM for the select element, then initialize select2 over it

Comment: @Rumplin, thanks for the response. I searched based on your suggestion but the resolution is still very elusive. Can you refer me something like a tutorial link? Thanks.